# Accessing array elements in a TypeSafe configuration

Tags: json, configuration, typesafe-config

Given a nested JSON as configuration, like:

```
{
    app: {
        id: "app1"
        instances: 2,
        servers: [
            { host: "farm1.myco.com", port: 9876 }
            { host: "farm2.myco.com", port: 9876 }
        ]
    }
}
```

When using typeSafe config, is it possible to address elements of an array directly in a path?

At the moment we need to do something like the following, which is kind of verbose:

```
val servers = config.getObjectList("app.servers")
val server = servers.get(0).toConfig
val host = server.getString("host")
val port = server.getInt("port")
```

Something like this would be ideal:

`val host = config.getString("app.servers.0.host")` ?

Does the TypeSafe API supports something like this?

Answer (score 3):

This seems not possible so far.
See https://github.com/typesafehub/config/issues/30

Answer (score 0):

Implement a helper function that transforms the object into something a little more manageable. This is what I ended up using.

```
def toList(jList:java.util.List[_ <: ConfigObject]) :  List[Config] = {
    val l = jList.asScala.toList
    val slConfig = l.map(item => {
        item.toConfig
    })

   slConfig
}
```

The use of that function would look like

```
val servers = toList(objectList)

for(server <- servers) {
    println(server.getString("host"))
    println(server.getString("port"))
}
```

Comment: The question is on how to address an element of the array. Imagine that your team members had `{name, age, zipcode}`. How could I get the zipcode of the first member?  That's what I want in my example above: The host and port of the first instance.